# A Database Error Occurred In codeigniter Error Number: 1048

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have problem at the time of input data to the database

**this is error message**

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1048
>
> Column 'username_member' cannot be null
>
> INSERT INTO `member` (`id_member`, `username_member`,
>   `password_member`, `nama_member`, `jk_member`, `hp_member`,
>   `alamat_member`, `email_member`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
>   NULL, NULL, NULL)
>
> Filename: C:/AppServ/www/PROJEK/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

**my controller**

```
function tambah()
{
    $data = array(
        'aksi' => site_url('member/tambah_aksi'),
        'id_member' => set_value('id_member'),
        'username_member' => set_value('username_member'),
        'password_member' => set_value('password_member'),
        'nama_member' => set_value('nama_member'),
        'jk_member' => set_value('jk_member'),
        'hp_member' => set_value('hp_member'),
        'alamat_member' => set_value('alamat_member'),
        'email_member' => set_value('email_member'),
        'button' => 'DAFTAR'
    );

    $this->load->view('Utama/member_form', $data);
}


function tambah_aksi()
{

    $data = array(
        'id_member' => $this->input->post('id_member'),
        'username_member' => $this->input->post('username_member'),
        'password_member' => $this->input->post('password_member'),
        'nama_member' => $this->input->post('nama_member'),
        'jk_member' => $this->input->post('jk_member'),
        'hp_member' => $this->input->post('hp_member'),
        'alamat_member' => $this->input->post('alamat_member'),
        'email_member' => $this->input->post('email_member')
    );

    $this->member_model->tambah_data($data);
    redirect('Login_member');
}
```

**View**

```
<h3>  FORM <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>Home" class="btn btn-large pull-right"><i class="icon-arrow-left"></i> LANJUT BERBELANJA </a></h3>  <hr class="soft"/>   <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr><th> FORM DAFTAR MEMBER </th></tr>




  <form action="<?php echo $aksi; ?>" method="get" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <tr> 
      <td>
      <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="inputUsername">Username</label>
      <div class="controls"> 
      </td>
      <td>
     <input type="text" name="username_member" class="form-control" placeholder="Inputkan Username" value="">
      </div>
      </div>
      </td>
      <tr>
      <td>
      <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword1">Password</label>
      <div class="controls">
      </td>
       <td>
      <input type="password" name="password_member" placeholder="Password"  value="">
      </div>
      </div>
      </td>
      </tr>

       <tr>
      <td>
      <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword1">Nama Member</label>
      <div class="controls">
      </td>
       <td>
      <input type="text" name="nama_member" placeholder="ex : Eden Hazard" value="">
      </div>
      </div>
      </td>
      </tr>

       <tr>
      <td>
      <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword1">Jenis Kelamin</label>
      <div class="controls">
      </td>
       <td>
       <input type="radio" name="jk_member" value="Laki">Pria
       <br>
       <input type="radio" name="jk_member" value="Wanita">Wanita
      </div>
      </div>
      </td>
      </tr>

       <tr>
      <td>
      <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword1">No Hp</label>
      <div class="controls">
      </td>
       <td>
      <input type="text" name="hp_member" placeholder="ex : 08127516331" value="">
      </div>
      </div>
      </td>
      </tr>

       <tr>
      <td>
      <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword1">Alamat Lengkap</label>
      <div class="controls">
      </td>
       <td>
      <input type="text" name="alamat_member" placeholder="ex : perum pandau blok c.19 no.16, Pekanbaru, Riau" value="">
      </div>
      </div>
      </td>
      </tr>

       <tr>
      <td>
      <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword1">Email</label>
      <div class="controls">
      </td>
       <td>
      <input type="text" name="email_member" placeholder="ex : randy@yahoo.com" value="">
      </div>
      </div>
      </td>
      </tr>



      <tr>

      <td>

    <input type="hidden" name="id_member" value="<?php echo $id_member; ?>">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><?php echo $button; ?></button>

      </td>

      </tr>
      </form>
```

Comment: Where does id_member come from? Is that your auto incremented field which is created when the insert is performed?

Comment: You should also be validating your form fields... Look up the CI validation class on how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to change your forms method from `get` to `post` as you are processing POST data.

So your line

```
<form action="<?php echo $aksi; ?>" method="get" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Change the get to post for your method.

```
<form action="<?php echo $aksi; ?>" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

See how that flies.